# How to subtract values in different sized vectors and use min for lookup

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have two .txt files that I have converted to vectors.

The first .txt file looks like:

```
X Y Pixel
3 3 10
12 12 210
```

The second .txt file looks like:

```
ID X Y Pixel
0  1 1  11
0  1 2  11
0  2 1  11
0  2 2  11
1  10 10 220
1  11 10 220
1  10 11 220
1  11 11 220
```

I have converted them to their respective matrices using:

```
testOne= fopen('test_file1.txt', 'r');
sizeOfTestOne = [4 Inf];
testMatrix = fscanf(testOne, '%d', sizeOfTestOne);
testMatrix = testMatrix’

testTwo = fopen('test_file2.txt', 'r');
sizeOfTestTwo = [3 Inf];
testTwoMatrix = fscanf(testTwo, '%d', sizeOfTestTwo);
testTwoMatrix = testTwoMatrix’
```

What I want to do is this:

I want to give the values in the first .txt file an ID (it will be either 0 or 1) using the values of the second .txt file.

I want to basically extract the entire row of the second .txt file where the difference of the X and Y values of the first .txt file and the second are the smallest..

So for example, the first one: 3, 3, 10
Scanning the values of the second .txt. file..

I know that the row I want is the 4th row (0, 2, 2, 11) because the difference between there X and Y values is 1 and 1 and the sum of these is 2, which is smaller than any of the other X and Y values.

And the second row will take the last row, because the difference between the X and Y values is also 1 and 1.

So I want to have the 3, 3, 10 row have an ID of 0 and the 12, 12, 210 row have a value of 1.

I hope this was clear.

Comment: What happens when two different IDs are equally close?

Comment: For what scenario? I am looking for the min, so 1, 2 and 2, 1 are technically the same but 1, 1 is smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rewriting your given setup code a bit:

```
f1 = fopen('test_file1.txt', 'r');
m1 = (fscanf(f1, '%d', [3 Inf]))';

f2 = fopen('test_file2.txt', 'r');
m2 = (fscanf(f2, '%d', [4 Inf]))';
```

Start by defining a metric distance between a row and a matrix:

```
dist = @(r, m) sum(abs(r - m), 2);
```

Now simply loop through all rows in `m1`:

```
ids = zeros(size(m1, 1), 1);

for i = [1:size(m1, 1)]
    [val, idx] = min(dist(m1(i, 1:3), m2(:, 2:4)));
    ids(i) = m2(idx, 1);
end

disp(ids)
```

Concatenate your `m1` with `ids` if desired:

```
m1 = [ids, m1];
```

Final result:

```
 0     3     3    10
 1    12    12   210
```